# I keep getting multiple errors each time I try to compile the program. Not sure where I went wrong

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeShop {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
//Welcome message
String username;

System.out.println("Please enter your name");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
username = keyboard.next();
System.out.println("Welcome to the Java Byte Code Coffee Shop," + username + "!");

//Menu
System.out.println("Here is our menu.");
System.out.println("1. Coffee $1.50");
System.out.println("2. Latte $3.50");
System.out.println("3. Cappuccino $3.25");
System.out.println("4. Expresso $2.00");

//Item selection
int item_Number;
System.out.println("Please enter an item number.");
Scanner item = new Scanner(System.in);
item_Number = item.nextInt();


if(item_Number == 1) {
item = 1.50;
}
if(item_Number == 2) {
item = 3.50;
}
if(item_Number == 3) {
item = 3.25;
}
if(item_Number == 4) {
item = 2.00; 
}

//Item Quantity
int quantity;
System.out.println("Please enter the quantity.");
Scanner amount = new Scanner(System.in);
quantity = amount.nextInt();
double total = quantity * item;
System.out.println("Total before discount and tax is " + total);
//Discount and tax
double nuTotal;
if(total >= 10) {
nuTotal = total - (total * .1);
} else {
nuTotal = total;
}
System.out.println("Your total with discount is " + nuTotal);
double totalTax = nuTotal * .07;
System.out.println("Your total with tax is " + totalTax);
System.out.println("Thank you " + username + "! Please stop by again!");

}
}
```

Your assignment is to write a program called CoffeeShop (in the file CoffeeShop.java) that simulates a virtual coffee shop, allowing the user to select an item to purchase, along with the quantity of that item. After obtaining the item selection and desired quantity from the user, your program should calculate the cost, tax, discount, and final cost, then display these to the user.

Comment: What are the multiple errors you're getting?

Comment: Check your "item" variable .. once it's a scanner, then you use it to try to store a double.

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts here:

```
Scanner item = new Scanner(System.in);
item_Number = item.nextInt();


if(item_Number == 1) {
item = 1.50;
}
if(item_Number == 2) {
item = 3.50;
}
if(item_Number == 3) {
item = 3.25;
}
if(item_Number == 4) {
item = 2.00; 
}
```

`item` is a `Scanner` object but then you attempt to assign it a `double` value.

Then `double total = quantity * item;`. You multiply by a `Scanner` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the following code.

First you declare:

```
Scanner item = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then you try to set that scanner variable to be what I presume to be the price.

```
if(item_Number == 1) {
item = 1.50;
}
if(item_Number == 2) {
item = 3.50;
}
if(item_Number == 3) {
item = 3.25;
}
if(item_Number == 4) {
item = 2.00; 
}
```

In order to fix this what you should do is set these numbers to a new variable, such as:

```
double price = 0;

price = ...; //not: item = ...;
```

Then you can calculate your total simply by:

```
double total = quantity * price;
```

Hope this helps! Just try to be very careful when setting variables :)

I believe your code should be similar to:

```
double price = 0;
if(item_Number == 1) {
    price = 1.50;
}
if(item_Number == 2) {
    price = 3.50;
}
if(item_Number == 3) {
    price = 3.25;
}
if(item_Number == 4) {
    price = 2.00; 
}

double total = quantity * price;
```

Comment: I did exactly what you posted above and now i get this error:

CoffeeShop.java:47: error: variable price might not have been initialized
double total = quantity * price;
                          ^

Comment: @RobertSemulka Did you declare it using `double price = 0;`? good point on that it might never be set

Comment: yes i did. thats why I'm not sure why i got that error

Comment: nevermind, it now compiles..
Total before discount and tax is 21.0
Your total with discount is 18.9
Your total with tax is 1.323
Thank you Robert! Please stop by again!

I need to Print each of my calculated dollar amounts (e.g. tax amount) with exactly two decimal places and i have  to display each dollar amount with a dollar sign.. any idea how to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you a bit!

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Welcome message
    String username;
    double item = 0.0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    System.out.println("Please enter your name");        
    username = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Java Byte Code Coffee Shop," + username + "!");

    //Menu
    System.out.println("Here is our menu.");
    System.out.println("1. Coffee $1.50");
    System.out.println("2. Latte $3.50");
    System.out.println("3. Cappuccino $3.25");
    System.out.println("4. Expresso $2.00");

    //Item selection
    int item_Number = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter an item number.");
    item_Number = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (item_Number == 1) {
        item = 1.50;
    }
    if (item_Number == 2) {
        item = 3.50;
    }
    if (item_Number == 3) {
        item = 3.25;
    }
    if (item_Number == 4) {
        item = 2.00;
    }

    //Item Quantity
    int quantity = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter the quantity.");
    quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
    double total = quantity * item;        
    System.out.println("Total before discount and tax is $ " + df.format(total));

    //Discount and tax
    double nuTotal;
    if (total >= 10) {
        nuTotal = total - (total * 0.10);
    } else {
        nuTotal = total;
    }
    System.out.println("Your total with discount is $" + df.format(nuTotal));
    double totalTax = nuTotal + (nuTotal * 0.07);
    System.out.println("Your total with tax is: $" + df.format(totalTax));
    System.out.println("Thank you " + username + "! Please stop by again!");

}
```

}

I advise you to follow name patterns for the Java programming language and its variables... you could see the documentation in here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

I also suggest you to initialize your variables in order to avoid Null values while validating.
Hope this helps! It's working already... but I'm not sure what are your expectations, good luck!

Comment: Total before discount and tax is 24.0
Your total with discount is 21.6
Your total with tax is: 1.5120000000000002
Thank you rob! Please stop by again!

How can i get the number value to read $24.00? also the total with tax is wrong...how do i fix that?

Comment: @RobertSemulka Okay, sir in order to format your "double" outputs you use the DecimalFormat class. Regarding to the values there was a sum missing because totalTax must be as follows: double totalTax = nuTotal + (nuTotal * 0.07);   please check the code changes above!